# Unknown modifier '(' when using preg_match() with a REGEX expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate dates like DD/MM/YYYY with PHP using preg_match(). This is what my REGEX expression looks like:

```
$pattern = "/^([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})$/";
```

But using it with a correct value, I get this message:

> preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('

Complete code:

```
    $pattern = "/^([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})$/";
    $date = "01/03/2011";

    if(preg_match($pattern, $date)) return TRUE;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Escape the `/` characters inside the expression as `\/`.

```
$pattern = "/^([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})$/";
```

As other answers have noted, it looks better to use another delimiter that isn't used in the expression, such as `~` to avoid the 'leaning toothpicks' effect that makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

You use `/` as delimiter and also in your expression. Now

```
/^([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)/
```

Is the "complete" expression and all following is expected as modifier, also the `(`.

You can simply use another delimiter.

```
~^([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})$~
```

Or you escape all occurence of `/` within the expression, but I would prefer another delimiter ;) Its more readable.

Answer (score 2):

your delimiter is /, but you are using it inside the pattern itself.
Use a different delimiter, or escape the /

Answer (score 1):

You could escape the slashes `/` as suggested. It'll eventually lead to the [Leaning Toothpick Syndome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome), though.

It's common to use different delimiters to keep your regular expression clean:

```
// Using "=" as delimiter
preg_match('=^ ... / ... $=', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

checek date using below function

```
 function checkDateFormat($date)
    {
      //match the format of the date
      if (preg_match ("/^([0-9]{2}) \/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/", $date, $parts))
      {
        //check weather the date is valid of not
        if(checkdate($parts[2],$parts[1],$parts[3]))
          return true;
        else
         return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }

echo checkDateFormat("29/02/2008"); //return true
echo checkDateFormat("29/02/2007"); //return false
```